# Error installing minqa in a non-standard location in Scientific Linux 6.6

Tags: r, linux, g++, lme4

I would ultimately like to install `lme4` for `R-3.2.5` on a system with Scientific Linux 6.6.  I'm on a shared system (I'm compiling `R` packages for a distributed computing problem), so I need to install all the packages to a non-standard location (`/a/lot/of/subdirectories/R-3.2.5` instead of the usual `/usr/local/`).

I've already encountered a lot of trouble installing the `lme4` dependency, `nloptr`, which would not install using the usual `install.packages` command in `R`.  I ended up downloading `nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz`, installing it, and then linking to the installed libraries when invoking `install.packages` in `R`.  I'm now having trouble installing the `minqa` library, which is another `lme4` dependency.  Here's the error message when I attempt to install `minqa` the following command in `R`: `install.packages("minqa")`

```
trying URL 'http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/minqa_1.2.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 53548 bytes (52 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 52 KB

* installing *source* package ‘minqa’ ...
** package ‘minqa’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c altmov.f -o altmov.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c bigden.f -o bigden.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c biglag.f -o biglag.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c bobyqa.f -o bobyqa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c bobyqb.f -o bobyqb.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c lagmax.f -o lagmax.o
g++ -I/var/lib/condor/execute/slot1/dir_20833/R-3.2.5/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/var/lib/condor/execute/slot1/dir_20833/R-3.2.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2  -c minqa.cpp -o minqa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c newuoa.f -o newuoa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c newuob.f -o newuob.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c prelim.f -o prelim.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c rescue.f -o rescue.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c trsapp.f -o trsapp.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c trsbox.f -o trsbox.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c trstep.f -o trstep.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c uobyqa.f -o uobyqa.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c uobyqb.f -o uobyqb.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c update.f -o update.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2  -c updatebobyqa.f -o updatebobyqa.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o minqa.so altmov.o bigden.o biglag.o bobyqa.o bobyqb.o lagmax.o minqa.o newuoa.o newuob.o prelim.o rescue.o trsapp.o trsbox.o trstep.o uobyqa.o uobyqb.o update.o updatebobyqa.o Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed -lgfortran -lm
g++: Fatal: No such file or directory
g++: error:: No such file or directory
g++: creating: No such file or directory
g++: temporary: No such file or directory
g++: file: No such file or directory
g++: for: No such file or directory
g++: '-e': No such file or directory
g++: failed: No such file or directory
make: *** [minqa.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/var/lib/condor/execute/slot1/dir_20833/R-3.2.5/lib64/R/library/minqa’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/var/lib/condor/execute/slot1/dir_20833/RtmpruzdgN/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("minqa") :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
```

It looks like `g++` from `install.packages` is trying to reference the location `/usr/local/lib64` instead of the actual location where I have `R` installed.  Any ideas of how to resolve this?  Is there an argument I can pass to `install.packages` (ex, with the `configure.args` option) to tell `g++` what to do?

Comment: The *no such file or directory* errors are suggesting a malformed command. Did you use `configure.args`? Could you please post your `install.packages` command?

Comment: @KevinArseneau updated. I'm just using `install.packages("minqa")`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with `minqa` specifically, but if you can assign the `--with-'minqa'-lib=<path> --with-'minqa'-include=<path>` values correctly, then I am assuming you should be able to build successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was multipronged:

1. Install `nloptr` from Github using `install_github` from the `devtools` package. The issue, I discovered, was that due to the workaround I had used to install `nloptr`, `minqa` was looking in the wrong place for the various `nloptr` libraries. The development version of `nloptr` on Github seems to use a different method for installing the `nlopt` libraries, which didn't throw an error
2. When invoking `install.packages`, use `lib=.libPaths()[2]` to set the right library path
3. When encountering errors using `install.packages` within R, try using `R CMD INSTALL` from outside R instead

Combined, these various methods seem to have solved all my issues.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things here.

*First*, the location does not matter.  R can use `.libPaths()`, or one of several environment variables, at ease to install whereever you want.  See `help(Startup)` for details, `install.packages()` also has a direct option.

*Second*, while your goal may be `lme4`, you need to tackle the dependencies one by one.  If `nloptr` is the problem, look at the numerous questions about it here. I contributed a patch to it which will make `nlopt` build against a system `libnlopt` -- then it is easy peasy (at least on Debian/Ubuntu).  Newer github source of `nloptr` also bundle it.

*Third*, does it *really* have to be Scientific Linux if all this is so difficult?  On several other flavors of Linux, this is simply `sudo apt-get install r-cran-lme4` and the package *and all its dependencies* will install from binaries.

Comment: I believe I can also use `CentOS 7`. Would that ease installation as you suggest?

Comment: Not fundamentally, as I was referring to advantages of Debian-based systems.  That said, you _can_ do all this as these are regular CRAN packages. But on those platforms the legwork is yours.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It did take a little legwork but I think I was able to solve my issue. I installed the Github version of `nloptr` which seems to have solved the issue with `minqa`. See my answer below.

Comment: Good to know :)